# Codeigniter Internationalization i18n trailing slash not added

Tags: codeigniter, internationalization, routes

I have a project going on, and now [admin section is almost done] (I know bit late) I am trying to implement [i18n](http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n) to the project.
I think everything works fine except when I enter `http://localhost/my_project` while my_project is working directory with CI installation in it, I am redirected to the following `http://localhost/my_project/enhome` (no trailing slash after `en`) any ideas?

Expecting result `http://localhost/my_project/en/home`, not just `home` controller but all controllers are behaving same.

`.htaccess`, `base_url` and `index_page` are set right (all works without the i18n).

**routes.php** are out of stock

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';

// URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
$route['^(en|de|fr|nl)/(.+)$'] = "$2";

// '/en', '/de', '/fr' and '/nl' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(en|de|fr|nl)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

**edit** 
I am using "new" [i18n](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n) from I guess ellislab. Sorry for wrong link (for 1.7 CI version).

Comment: how are you redirecting it? Can you post that code?

Comment: I am not redirecting anything library (i18n does all the work) on other projects it works out of box. But on this one there is problem with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some digging, I found the problem in core file, on the bottom of this posted script there is variable `$new_url` and it was echoing `Redirect triggered to http://192.168.1.184/my_project/enhome` without the "fix". I just added the `/` in there and it works prefectly I wonder what happend here and if this is `OK` fix or not.

```
function MY_Lang() {
    parent::__construct();

    global $CFG;
    global $URI;
    global $RTR;


    $this->uri = $URI->uri_string();
    $this->default_uri = $RTR->default_controller;

    $uri_segment = $this->get_uri_lang($this->uri);
    $this->lang_code = $uri_segment['lang'] ;

    $url_ok = false;
    if ((!empty($this->lang_code)) && (array_key_exists($this->lang_code, $this->languages)))
    {
        $language = $this->languages[$this->lang_code];
        $CFG->set_item('language', $language);
        $url_ok = true;
    }

    if ((!$url_ok) && (!$this->is_special($uri_segment['parts'][0]))) // special URI -> no redirect
    { 
      // set default language
      $CFG->set_item('language', $this->languages[$this->default_lang()]);

      $uri = (!empty($this->uri)) ? $this->uri: $this->default_uri;
      //OPB - modification to use i18n also without changing the .htaccess (without pretty url) 
      $index_url = empty($CFG->config['index_page']) ? '' : $CFG->config['index_page']."/";
      $new_url = $CFG->config['base_url'].$index_url.$this->default_lang()."/".$uri;
      echo "Redirect triggered to ".$new_url;

      //header("Location: " . $new_url, TRUE, 302);
      // exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this library is little old never been updated author since long time and it works for CI 1.7 but here is updated version compatible with CI 2.1.* same library but updated version working same way you can download from here

[CodeIgniter 2.1 internationalization i18n](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n)

Comment: I am using new one :) from github.

Comment: i have used the same one for my recent project and no problem at all

Comment: I am using it on different projects also! (no problems). But now this new problem popped out that trailing slash is not inserted after "auto redirect" (from `localhost/my_project/whatever` to `localhost/my_project/en/whatever`) it actually redirects to `localhost/my_project/enwhatever`.